# I need to copy the live web data to new column after each minute, stuck in following code to move to next column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, timer

```
Sub Timer()

Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:50"), "Main"

End Sub

Sub Main()

j = 5
   
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range(Cells(5, 5), Cells(19, 5)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dashbord").Select
    Cells(5, j).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
         
j = j + 1
        
    Call Timer
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "stuck in following code" is not a useful description of the exact problem you're having when you run your code.

Comment: forgive me for the title, i was learning for getting it done from youtube but couldnt get it, i am novice for programming..

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim j As Long

Sub Start()
    j=5
    NextRun
End Sub

Sub NextRun()
     Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:50"), "Main"
End Sub

Sub Main()

    Dim rng As range
   
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(5, 5), .Cells(19, 5))
    End with
    
    Sheets("Dashbord").Cells(5, j).Resize( _
       rng.rows.count, rng.columns.count).value =  rng.value
         
    j = j + 1
        
    NextRun
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do i need to initialise any library at start , it is giving run-time error 1004,  application define or object define error

Comment: on which line, and when does that happen?

Comment: Sheets("Dashbord").Cells(5, j).Resize( _
       rng.rows.count, rng.columns.count).value =  rng.value

Comment: What's the value of j when it fails?

Comment: got it mate, with your help of defining j outside main sub.   Thnks for your help...!

Comment: hello Tim, the macro is running fine, but there is one problem whenever i open another file the values get pasted in that sheet. please help me out here.@TimWilliams

Comment: `Sheets("Dashbord")` has no workbook specified, so it will default to whichever workbook is active, provided it has a worksheet with that name.  If you need to copy to a specific workbook then you need to include that in your code. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashbord")` if the sheet is in the workbook where the code is running.

Comment: Hello @Tim , please help me out to carry same code each time the cell value in copy range is changed instead of the time interval. This is running good but if the cell is not changed in given time interval we get too many zero columns in post processing comparisons.

Comment: You can use the worksheet_calculate event for that.